# Lots of PHP processes running at the same time

Tags: php, cron

**Requirements**

I have a web app which allow users schedule some social media tasks like posting on Facebook or Twitter.

Each user can tell the app to publish on his social media accounts at any time (14:00, 15:11, 17:54...).

Besides this, I need to complete other tasks for each user every day such as getting their followers/friends or who unfollowed them on Twitter.

**Situation**

So far, I have had a file for each task (post.php, getFollowers.php, analytics.php...). For example:

*post.php*

I have created a cron job for this script which check every minute if some post must be published. Let's assume we run the script and it finds three users who want to tweet at this time, it will iterate the users with a foreach loop and post in every accounts.

...the other scripts do the same: get every users who want to do something, create a queue and iterate it.

**The problems**

1. Posting task requires being completed on time.
2. Some long tasks like get followers require running every day.

(1) Posting on Twitter and Facebook takes 30-40s, so if five users want to post at 14:00, it will be late for the 3, 4 and 5.

(2) Getting some followers of one user takes 40-60s, so just with 1000 users the script would spend 11-16h which definitely is not scalable. I should be able to get this task done in just 2-3h.

**Solution?**

I have thought I could solve both problems by separating user tasks and executing a process for each user.

Is this a correct and scalable solution? How would you solve these problems in a scalable way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not going to help. `exec()` blocks until whatever you're execing completes. you'd have to put that job in the background, e.g. `exec('somejob &')`, which then opens up a whole other set of problems.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc. I didn't know it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your architecture like? Do you have a worker tier? This [article](https://medium.com/@sunils34/the-cronjob-that-generates-4-million-a-year-4540b0cde584#.kqqu45ek1) might be of interest.

Comment: Might be worth looking into AWS or other cloud services to offload the large amount processes without worrying about your server performance

Comment: @FrancisEytanDortort I have a simple shared server on Hostgator. Interesting article.  But how they can post every user post on time with one script?

Comment: @SageArslan Yes, It looks a good solution, would you recommend me a particular AWS product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a managed, distributed scheduled task service, such as AWS Elastic Beanstalk [Worker Tier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) or [IronWorker](http://www.iron.io/worker/).

With AWS EB, you would include in your project a `cron.yaml` file containing a config such as:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "post"
   url: "/post"
   schedule: "* * * * *"
```

Which will trigger a POST request to `http://localhost/post` every minute.

I would also suggest that the scheduled task itself *not* send the posts, but rather trigger other, multiple, tasks to do so. Using AWS EB, you would do so using the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-sqs.html):

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;

$aws = Aws::factory('/path/to/my_config.json');
$client = $aws->get('Sqs');

$client->sendMessage(array(
    'QueueUrl'     => $queueUrl,
    'MessageBody'  => json_encode($post),
    'DelaySeconds' => $delay,
));
```

This will trigger a POST request to your configured URL for the Worker Tier (ie. `http://localhost/worker`) for every message with the JSON encoded data in the body.

This approach allows you to better scale with the number of posts to send simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So... With multiple tasks I will received a request for the file which uses the AWS SDK, it will process post information and it will schedule a message in the queue. Then that queue would send a request to my server on time with the information. Did I understand it well?

Comment: Yes. The scheduled task would look for posts to be published in the next minute, for example, then create a message in the queue for each post with a delay of 60 seconds. Each message will then trigger its own http request after the given delay. You can increase the delay to up to 15 minutes. The advantage of having a long delay is that you can use the queue size to trigger scaling up the number of worker instances.

Comment: Thanks Francis, nice explanation. I would have to hire https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/, wouldn't I? Do you know if I could use cron.yaml in a Hostgator shared server?. I suppose if some user deletes a post I will be able to delete de the message. Thanks again

Comment: My explanation is for use with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Meaning, at least the Worker Tier, would have to be hosted on AWS. (BTW, some resources are [free](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) for the first year.) You can read up on the service [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html), there is a [walkthrough on deploying an app](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.Walkthrough.html) and [php specific details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.sdlc.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use a queue and worker system.

The queue, eg: Amazon SQS:

1. The user schedules things to happen at X time.
2. The cron runs periodically, finding jobs that need to run.
3. The cron script pops the job into the queue.

The worker:

1. Asks the queue for a job
2. Does the job
3. Goto 1

The trick is you have one queue, and then as many worker processes/servers as is necessary to keep the queue from growing continuously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this manner I will schedule tasks on Amazon SQS and it will call workers processes on my server that would do the job for every single user. Did I understand it well?

Comment: Almost, you need to start up workers and they ask the queue for work. The benefit is you can start up as many as you need, and stop them whenever you like. The truly "cloudy" solution is to automate spinning workers processes/servers up/down depending on the demand at any given time.